# "trust the thrust" idiom

Tags: idioms

What does "trust the thrust" mean?

I found only one definition of the phrase, in the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trust%20the%20Thrust):

> A statement defining the special bond needed between two young men to properly bounce a yoga ball between their chests, but can be applied to any non-sexual thrusting activity.

But this definition didn't make clear it to me... So I will be very grateful for any comprehensive example.

Comment: What's the context?  This is not a common idiom, and may be a quote from some media source.  Your guess is as good as ours.

Answer (score 3):

The Urban Dictionary has a lot of idioms that are either uncommon or specific to a very small subgroup of people.  You're not going to get any comprehensive examples for an idiom like this.  Likely, someone said it once, a couple people found it amusing because it rhymes, and it ended up on Urban Dictionary.

Comment: Also keep in mind that anyone can add to Urban Dictionary, so don't take everything for granted.